# Reference on a paper by Riemann on Fourier

Tags: reference-request, fourier-series

I was watching a video on PDEs and when arriving at the part of Fourier Series, the professor said:

> And one of the most fascinating reads I ever had was a paper by Riemann on the history of this [Fourier Series].

I tried looking for it but didn't succeed, and I was wondering if anyone could provide a link or a reference to this paper.

Thank you very much.

In case you need it, the link of the video is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cf8rgx60IKA on the minute 14:21 (The audio on that specific part is messed up, so be careful if you are using headphones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riemann only wrote one paper on Fourier series: his Habilitation thesis "Über die Darstellbarkeit einer Function durch eine trigonometrische Reihe" (On the representability of a function by a trigonometric series). This is where he famously what it means for a function to be integrable in the manner named after him, and less famously, integrates by parts a couple of times.

A transcription is available [here](http://www.emis.de/classics/Riemann/Trig.pdf). Translations are hard to come by (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/30328/69658) for some references). There is a French edition of Riemann's Oeuvres available [here](https://archive.org/details/oeuvresmathmat00riem) if French is more comprehensible than German, but otherwise you'll probably have to hunt down the [Kendrick Press translation](http://www.kendrickpress.com/Riemann.htm) by Baker, Christenson and Orde.

Answer (score 1):

That's Riemann's *Habilitationsschrift*: "Ueber die Darstellbarkeit einer Function durch eine trigonometrische Reihe". (1853-1854)

**Reference might be formatted like this:**

G.F.B. Riemann, Ueber die Darstellbarkeit einer Function durch eine trigonometrische Reihe. In: Bernhard Riemann, *Gesammelte mathematische Werke*, Leipzig, Teubner, 1892, pp.227-264

PDF link:
http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Trig/Trig.pdf

Google books:
G F B Riemann, Gesammelte mathematische Werke, pp.227-264
https://books.google.com/books?id=fSzfCXZrvOwC